# Prometheus configuration and http_requests_total

Tags: prometheus

Ι have installed prometheus with the default configuration.

I am at its web interface, on http://localhost/9090/metrics trying to fetch the time series corresponding to the total of `http` requests.

Filtering out by the name `http_requests_total`, retrieves several time series with different labels, e.g.

```
http_requests_total{code='200',handler='targets',instance=localhost:9090,job='prometheus',method='get'} 
http_requests_total{code='200',handler='static',instance=localhost:9090,job='prometheus',method='get'} 
http_requests_total{code='200',handler='graph',instance=localhost:9090,job='prometheus',method='get'} 
[...]
```

what are all these time series? how can I find the semantics behind each label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, if you visit http://localhost:9090/metrics in your browser, you should see something along the lines of:

```
# HELP prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds Histogram of latencies for HTTP requests.
# TYPE prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds histogram
prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{handler="/",le="0.1"} 3
prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{handler="/",le="0.2"} 3
prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{handler="/",le="0.4"} 3
...
```

which should explain what the metric measures and hopefully what the labels are intended to represent. If you don't know what a counter/gauge/histogram is, then you should probably [RTFM](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/).

And if you want to go in deeper (and have access to the source code of the monitored service, as is the case with Prometheus source code), you can [search said source code for the metric name](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/search?q=http_request_duration_seconds&unscoped_q=http_request_duration_seconds). Note that the metric name in the code may be a substring of the final metric name, as a namespace may be prepended to it (the `prometheus_` part in my example above) and for histograms and summaries `_count` or `bucket` or something else may be appended. So in the case of the metric above you should [search the code for "http_request_duration_seconds"](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/search?q=http_request_duration_seconds&unscoped_q=http_request_duration_seconds) rather than "prometheus_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket".